# How do I specify a degree character (U+00B0) in a Label

Tags: codenameone

I'm specifying the degree character as '\u00B0', which is the proper unicode code point, but it's showing up as the inverted exclamation point! I put it in a Label. When I run it in the simulator it shows up as the degree character, as it should, but on my Android, it's the inverted exclamation point. I'm doing this on the Mac using IntelliJ. Does anyone else see this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `nbproject/project.properties` and edit the `source.encoding` property to UTF-8 instead of the current default.

Comment: Thanks. I never thought of looking in the nbproject folder because I'm using IntelliJ. Now I know better.